# How to get back to the head of a singly linked list after creating it in java?

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am writing a program to slice a number into its digits and to store the digits in a linked list in reverse order. But I am not able to understand how to return the linked list?

I have tried creating a head ListNode but failed in it.

```
public class ListNode {
   int val;
   ListNode next;
   ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
  }

class Solution{
  int sum=123;
  public ListNode sol(){
    answer = new ListNode(0);  
    while (sum > 0) {
     int digit = sum % 10;
     answer= new ListNode(digit);
     answer= answer.next;
     sum /= 10;
                    }
        return //////
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
answer = new ListNode(0);
```

That `ListNode` instance is the first element, and thus the "root" of your list. But your list is only singly linked. You can't get back to a previous element! You have to remember where it started!

In other words, you have two options:

- turn your list into a double-linked list (so: each node remembers its predecessor) or
- remember that root node.

In other words: when using `answer` as the "moving pointer" within your list, then you should do something like:

```
root = new ListNode(0); // remember this, it is the start of the list!
answer = root;
```

And then you have to ensure to keep `root` around and unchanged! Because that reference represents the (one and only!) entrance to your list data. When you lose that, everything is lost ;-)